# Improve SSRS Report execution

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We have a SQL statement that executes in 0:07 seconds in Management Studio, its a query that returns some data like:

```
[Company Department] - [Exprense Type] - [Year/Month] - [Foreseen Budget] - [Expenses]
```

It's a 53k lines result. One calculated field is created on the dataset (`Budget - Expenses`).

In the SSRS report we have a matrix that shows the data like:

```
Columns: [Year/Month] (Group)
         [Foreseen Budget] [Expenses] [Foreseen Budget - Expenses]

Lines: [Company Department][Expense Type]
```

When I try to generate the report I get 5 minutes in SSRS.

In the log I get :

```
TimeDataRetrieval:440   
TimeProcessing: 8056
TimeRendering:39603
Start Time: 2016-08-24 16:40:26.030
End Time: 2016-08-24 16:41:14.220
```

It's like 1 minute in SSRS, which is acceptable, but in real execution the report only appears 5 minutes later.

What is happening, and how can I improve the real execution time?

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522806(v=sql.105).aspx#Process) is helpful.

Comment: When dealing with a big number of rows, I found out it's quite helpful to create a temp table from within the report query and use this table as source. Furthermore it might be helpful to move the calculation you mentioned into the query itself, so SSRS has nothing to do but to display the results.

Comment: It looks like the bulk of this time is spent "rendering", which has included on-demand evaluation since SSRS 2008.  Essentially, those are the functions inside the report itself.  Complex expressions/calculated fields or functions within grouping expressions are likely culprits.  There's also a chance that some more traditional rendering elements are the cause, but it didn't sound like your report was formatting-heavy.  In any event, some detail or investigation is needed to find the exact cause.  Edit: Also, if you use [&TotalPages] anywhere, delete that and see how it runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some suggestions came, I got that the problem was the total lines and then group then by date.

So I made a sollution in 2 steps:
1. I made a temptable with all the results 
2. I worked in summarize the data in the table not in SSRS

Doing that I got a 1 minute report rendering.

Thanks folks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

What format are you rendering as? Are you viewing the rows from browser? It will take quite a bit of time for the SSRS engine to render and draw up 53K rows.

Here are a few suggestions:
You could make use of pagination - Only show a few rows at a time? Change the datasource to bring back a few rows at a time selecting from a temp table as Tyron suggested
Have you tried to use report process caching? This could help reduce the processing time

Ive described an example on this post:
[SSRS with custom paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417833/ssrs-with-custom-paging/39432788#39432788)