# SSRS with custom paging

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am working on a SQL Server report which shows the data of size 300 K and therefore it is very slow most of the time is spent on the report processing.  So I m thinking if I can do some program to  get the data from the database per page.  This way call from the db and report processing time will reduce.  So in other words if I am showing 50 records per page and when I am on page one and click on page 2 or the next button, my report get the data from 51 to 100.   When I click on the next button again then I get the data for page 3 which would be 101 to 150.

So is there any way I can achieve.

Comment: If you did not read [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522806(v=sql.105).aspx), it could help you

Answer (score 0):

Usually when the report is rendered all the data is pulled and SSRS renders the report which causes delay. If performance is the key here, you could use a stored procedure to retrieve 50 rows at a time, instead of passing all the values directly to SSRS - caveat here is you wont be able to use the native next/previous page buttons for this.

A work around is to create custom links to loop back to the report itself with incremented parameters specifying an index row to start from.

Create a stored procedure that takes in a parameter which specifies the starting row from your table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetData

@RowNumber BIGINT

AS

  BEGIN

      DECLARE @FirstRow BIGINT
      DECLARE @LastRow BIGINT

      SET @FirstRow = @RowNumber
      SET @LastRow = @RowNumber + 50

    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
      SELECT *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY num) AS RowNumber
      FROM   dbo.TestTable
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM   CTE
    WHERE  RowNumber >= @FirstRow
           AND RowNumber < @LastRow

  END

GO
```

Create a stored procedure that retrieves the total rows from your table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetTotalRows

AS

BEGIN

    SELECT COUNT(*) "TotalRows"
    FROM dbo.TestTable

END

GO
```

Create the report and add the two datasets using the two stored procedures.

The `@RowNumber` parameter should be automatically generated. You can set the default value to 1 to start the report from row 1.

Create two "custom" buttons on the report (effectively just links back to the same report). You could use text boxes for Previous/Next Page buttons.

For the "Previous Button" Text Box - Properties > Action > Go to report > Specify a report (select the name of your report name). Add Parameter and set the expression to:
`=Parameters!RowNumber.Value-50`

For the "Next Button" Text Box - Properties > Action > Go to report > Specify a report (select the name of your report name). Add Parameter and set the expression to:
`=Parameters!RowNumber.Value+50`

You can also change the visibility options for the buttons (such as hiding "Previous Page" button when `Parameters!RowNumber.Value = 1`, or hiding the "Next Page" button when `Parameters!RowNumber.Value + 50 >= DataSetName!TotalRows.Value`)

Comment: Louie,  on given solution, how would I send the page number parameter back to the stored procedure.  Also how would i trigger an event from the next button on the report to get the next set of 50 records?

Comment: User - You can increment the parameter by creating a custom link to the same report and incrementing it in the expression section. I've updated me answer to make it more clear. Unfortunately you cannot use the native next/previous button pages. I've tested this in my lab and it works fine